# Determine if go binary called from interactive session

Tags: linux, go

I am writing a wrapper for yum to ensure interactive usage adheres to change-control processes. I don't want to affect non-interactive execution of yum (e.g. by Puppet).  If it was invoked interactively, the wrapper does some other work, if not it simply passes everything to the yum binary. So, I am looking for a way to determine if yum was called from an interactive session or not (tty attached?).

Is there a way to determine this?

Comment: What is your wrapper supposed to do? What exactly should be different between interactive or non-interactive use?

Comment: Most CLI utilities check for a tty rather than trying to guess what the parent process is.

Comment: Would [expect](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) do what you need without a wrapper program?

Comment: Even if you find out some details about the parent process, it does not necessarily tell you if your program is called interactively.

Comment: @GGSec Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't use comments for this purpose. And what is the wrapper supposed to do when it is run interactively or when it is run from a user-defined shell script? Why does Puppet run the wrapper instead of `yum`? Adding more details to the question might help to find a solution.